# Images and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting to use bootstrap to code a website, but I'm running into issues with some of the images that I put on a particular webpage. I want all four of the images to be the same size, but some of them aren't. Can a change in image resolution change how it is displayed on the webpage??

```
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
     <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <a href="google.com">
            <img src="/images/book-photo.jpg"" width="300" height="200" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            <h4>Books</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="/images/sports-photo2.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
          <h4>Sports</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="/images/concerts-photo.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
          <h4>Concerts</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="/images/sublease-photo.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
          <h4>Subleases</h4>
          <span class="text-danger">Coming Soon</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Example of different image sizes:
[image: Example of different image sizes]

Comment: There is a typo in the code. src="/images/book-photo.jpg"" - the last double quotes need to be removed.

Comment: Why are you setting a `width` and `height` on each image while using `.img-responsive`?

Comment: I fixed the typo, but the second and fourth images are still different sizes. Also, should I not use width and height for .img-responsive @J. Titus? If not, please explain why. I'm still learning.

Comment: The whole idea of `.img-responsive` is to dynamically set the size of the image to take up as much space as possible in a column, depending on the size of the viewport. You should not use `.img-responsive` if you have statically sized images.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your stylesheet for the markup you provided.

Comment: Thanks @J. Titus. That makes sense

Comment: @BrandonElder I'm just using the default bootstrap css stylesheet if that's what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to take up the same amount of space, set those as the background of the divs instead. Background-size:cover will make it take up the whole height/width of the div without stretching the photo. It will just cut off the sides a little to make it stay the same proportion. Background-position:center center will make the photo centered vertically and horizontally in the divs. You would just need to place a set height on the divs for the background to show.

Comment: I've never done this before. Am I going to have to go and edit the bootstrap css files?

Comment: hmm...that's a cool solution.  Will the divs still be responsive?

Comment: Yes responsive, no you don't need to edit bootstrap css files, here's an example of what I did for this YMCA website, https://cyedc.org/     It's the 3 blocks on the home page. For this one, I put a div inside the column and gave the div a set height, but that's because I needed to put text over it. You could do it the same why I did, or just put it on the column itself.